# What is an open property?

Tags: reference-request, notation, dynamical-systems

From an academic paper,

"the existence of elliptic or hyperbolic 2-periodic orbits is an open property".

I have never seen the term "open property" used before, moreover the paper gives no suggestion as to what it is?

Comment: An open property is a property that holds on an open subset (of some relevant space).

Comment: More specifically, the set of points having that proprety is open. You may find this paper relevant for what you've been reading: http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0201096

Comment: Thats the paper the problem came from

Comment: @QiaochuYuan is it like holomorphic: if true on $p$, then true on a neighbourhood of $p$ (unlike continuous, differentiable, twice differentiable but like real or complex-analytic i believe) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is like holomorphic: if true on p, then true on a neighbourhood of p (unlike continuous, differentiable, twice differentiable but like real or complex-analytic i believe) ?

See here for an example:

[Is twice differentiability an open property?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2546253/is-twice-differentiability-an-open-property)