# Is twice differentiability an open property?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

A function $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} $ which is differentiable at a point $a \in \mathbb{R}$ need not be differentiable in a neighbourhood of $a$. For example,
$$
f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} : x \mapsto \begin{cases}
x^2 && x \in \mathbb{Q} \\
-x^2 && x \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}
\end{cases}
$$
is differentiable only in $0$.

If $f$ is twice differentiable in $a$, then of course $f$ is differentiable in a neighbourhood of $a$. But is $f$ twice differentiable in a neighbourhood of $a$? I find it hard to come up with a natural counterexample, but see no reason why this statement should hold either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the following works:

Let $h: \mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a function that is everywhere continuous but nowhere differentiable. (Ask [Weierstraß](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_function).)

Let $g(x) := x^2\cdot h(x)$.
$g$ is everywhere continuous, but is differentiable only at $0$.
(If it were differentiable at $x\neq 0$, then so would be $h(x) = \frac{g(x)}{x^2}$. On the other hand, at $x=0$, since $h$ is continuous it is bounded on every finite-length interval around $0$, and $x^2 \cdot B(x)$ has derivative $0$ at $0$ for a bounded function $B$.)

Since $g$ is continuous, it has an antiderivative $f$. This $f$ is an example which shows that the answer to your question is "No".

Comment: This is exactly the answer I was going to give. (I'd be happier if you said it _is_ differentiable only at $0$, instead of "should be", and saying "$g$ is "integrable" bothers me...)

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich: I have edited regarding your first point and added a sketch of proof. I also sympathise with your second point, but I have settled on that expression for now until you convince me of a better one. (I first hesitated to write whether it is integrable in the sense of Riemann or Lebesgue, but obviously it's both, although in the context of antiderivatives one would think of the Riemann integral first.)

Comment: It's really not important, but if $h$ is what I think it is then $g$ is not Lebesgue integrable. It's locally integrable. Again, not important but I would have just said "since $g$ is continuous it has an antiderivative $f$".

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich: Just as I had written the comment, I had the afterthought "... on every interval of finite length". Anyway, I will take your final suggestion, thanks.